# Python: how to concatenate multiple pandas dataframes to produce a box-and-whisker plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

Say I have a dataset of values that were binned. The bins are stored in a dictionary called `mydict`. To obtain the histogram quantities needed to plot a Box-and-Whisker, I have done:

`df_dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([ (k, pd.Series(v)) for k,v in mydict.items() ]))`

To get the histogram quantities:

```
mydict_min = df_dataset.min()
mydict_max = df_dataset.max()
mydict_median = df_dataset.median()
mydict_1st3rd = df_dataset.quantile([.1, .3])
```

My problem: I need to plot a **[Box-and-Whisker plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)** given the histogram quantities shown above. How can I do this by using [DataFrame.boxplot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html)? In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712627/python-matplotlib-box-plot?answertab=active#tab-top) a Box-and-Whisker was built by doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'Parameter': ['A',]*8, 
                'Site': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2'],
                'Value':  [2.34, 2.67, 2.56, 2.89, 3.45, 4.45, 3.67, 4.56]})

df.boxplot(by=['Parameter', 'Site'])
plt.show()
```

Do I need to create a DataFrame of DataFrames? I already have the histogram quantities (shown above) and need no grouping. **How could I amend this code to include my histogram quantities?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief search I have figured out there is no need to concatenate anything. The simple answer is to construct the Box-and-Whisker from the `df_dataset`, as it already is a `series` and as such it stores all the relevant histogram quantities.

The line creating the Box-and-Whisker is:
`df_dataset.plot.box()`

Further information can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Details such as axis titles, plot title, grids, bins, and everything else can be set based on one's needs.